# Pseudo class within a class without div or span

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if a pseudo class can be placed for a specific class. For instance,

```
<p> You can get youtube <a class="video" href="www.video.com"> here </a> </p>.
```

What I want to do is to create a css file for class video within  itself and access pseudo classes like hover,active and visited.

I know one way of doing it is

```
<p> <span class="video"> You can get video <a href="www.video.com"> here </a> </span> </p>
```

And write css file as

```
.video a:hover{something}
.video a:active{something}
```

But I don't want to use the span/div for it. I would like to write my html as

```
 <a class="something" href="something.com">
```

and still access the pseudo classes of "a" for the class "video". Is it possible?

Comment: `a.something:hover`, `a.something:focus`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your file video.css, you can do something like that :

```
.video:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Pseudo class will be applied on all tag with class video.

You can also write something like this if class video can be on other tag than "a" tag :

```
a.video:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Pseudo class will be applied only on "a" tag with class video. Note that there is no space between "a" and ".video" because the class video is on "a" tag.